# Spring MVC - testing services

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, spring-mvc, spring-mvc-test

i have a question regarding service layer testing in Spring framework.
I have a class ProductService which has method:

```
public List<Product> getProducts() {
    return productDAO.getProducts();
}
```

Is there any way to test it properly? This method retrieve all products using dao layer, when i, for example fill a list with five products(which are in database right now) and test this method by asserting size of the list it seems useless because when i add one product it still passes, but it shouldn't - after adding one product it should return 6 not 5 products...
If you have any usefull sites/yt videos about spring unit testing please let me know.
Thanks for Your help in advance!
Regards

Answer (score 1):

One technique you could use to test this particular code is to mock the productDAO using a framework.  The mock object then provides specific results that you can test for in your unit tests.

Comment: thank you for your answer, im using mockito and hamcrest. Im using MockMvc and mockito for mocking dao. My question was how to properly cover this code like i wrote earlier when i mock productDao and hardcode that method return 5 products(for example) and after that i will put one more product into database it still passes but it shouldn't (there will be 6 products in database, and assert in unit test will expect 5 products. So maybe it's useless to cover this code with unit tests and i should write unit tests for DAO classes only? thanks for your answer!